# Error [Assetic\Exception\FilterException] Symfony Assetic with Less Css

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I am trying to configure symfony assetic manager to compile my less css files and rewrite paths however I am getting the following error:

```
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.
18:51:01 [file+] C:/htdocs/site-ideiah-symfony/app/../web/css/57b3454.css
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
An error occurred while running:
"C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Temp\ass1C74.tmp"

Error Output:
Access Denied
```

My config.yml

```
filters:
    cssrewrite: 
        apply_to: '\.(css|less)$'
    less: 
        node: [ "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" ]      
        node_paths: [ "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\", "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\" ]
        apply_to: "\.less$"
```

My template usage

```
  {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets filter='less,cssrewrite'
            '@IdeiahSiteAppBundle/Resources/public/less/style.less'
        %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

I am using Windows 8 with PHP 5.4.7, Does anyone knows how could i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Removing Less and installing an older version fixed it for me. One of the other solutions seems to be upgrading symfony to a newer version, but we were unable to do this because of having to use an older version of symfony which is compatible with centos6.5

This helped: https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/issues/217

Answer (score 1):

The `Error Output: Access Denied` message implies that it is a security related issue.

This security issue can be related to either 1) not being able to write the output files, 2) not being able to read the input files, and/or 3) not being able to execute the `node` command

1) Is the user that is running the `assetic:dump` command able to write to the folder `C:/htdocs/site-ideiah-symfony/web/css/` and the `57b3454.css` file ?

2) After the `Error Output:`, assetic should also display the input used, similar to this:

```
Input:
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "mixins.less";

// CSS Reset
@import "reset.less";
```

Do *you* see any input listed ?

3) Check if the user execute `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"` from the command-line